# Add record to the store and display on the grid

Tags: extjs

I have AddRecord method, that should add the record to the store and display on the grid that record.

I've put the form inside the window, and that is fine.
I was looking at the documentation but I got lost a bit. 
There is a fiddle created. 
Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2tuf

```
AddRecord: function (grid, rowId, record) {
        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
              title: "Add Person",
              height: 200,
              width: 400,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            closable: true,

          items: [{
              xtype:'form',
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                layout: 'anchor',

             items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                    name: 'First Name',
                    type: 'String',
                    allowBlank: false
                }, {
                    fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    name: 'Last Name',
                    type: 'String',
                    allowBlank: false
                }, ],
             buttons: [{
                text: 'Add',
                 formBind: true,
                 disabled: true,
                 handler: function () {

                         var record = Ext.getStore().getAt(rowId);
                         var store = grid.getStore('store.Personal')
                         var form = this.up('form').grid.getStore();
                         if (form.isValid()) {
                             form.add({
                                 success: function (record) {
                                     var store = grid.getStore('store.Personal')
                                     store.add(record);
                                 },
                             })

                         }
                 },
             }, {
                     text: 'Close', handler: function () {
                        this.up('window').close();
             }

         }],

          }]

     }).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, You made a little confusion about grid.getStore(), as it  just

> Returns the store associated with this Panel.

and how you are getting your form values, I think you were trying to do something like this:

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Add',
    formBind: true,
    disabled: true,
    handler: function(button) {
        let formValues = this.up('form').getForm().getValues(); //get the form Values
        let form = this.up('form').getForm(); //get the form itself
        var store = grid.getStore(); //get Store of your grid
        if (form.isValid()) {
            //add the formvalues to store
            store.add(formValues);
        }
    },
}]
```

I also made a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2tui)

Comment: I'm reading my data through the proxy, which has configured API, reader json, which loads the grid store. 
I have error now add is not defined at this line
store.add(formValues)

Comment: Humm, your grid component has a store, right? what's the value of your `store` var? You can also try to get the store by its id, using `Ext.getStore('yourStoreId')`

Comment: Yes it has, I've tried using the same store var as I was using on my OnDelete method. 
There I had rowId parameter so it was easier to locate the store.
Using  var store = Ext.getStore('store.Personnel'); 
I have this error: 
Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
And the store itself on console.log shows undefined.

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, in your store properties, you haven't defined a `storeId`, define it as `storeId:'PersonnelStore'` and  then use `Ext.getStore('PersonnelStore')`